# Changing the column width in Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Changing the column width in SQL server Transaction Replication.
Can we do direct width change ? or we need to takeout the article and modify.
This change replicate to subscriber? or we need to do manually at subscriber

Answer (score 2):

Changing the width of a column on a replicated table should be able to be done with a direct change without having to rebuild the replication.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to remove the table from your publication. Make the change, and then add it back into you publication. This will ensure that the table structure matches between the two databases. Step overview is below:

- Remote article from your publication (this will invalidate your snapshot)
- Run the snapshot agent (it won't push anything as nothing needs to be pushed - this step is even debatable)
- Make your change to the table in question
- Add the table / article back into your publication
- Push a new snapshot (it will only push the article that was just added)